# Rotate through numerous galleries with one set of thumbnails

Tags: javascript, gallery

I am creating a product page in a checkout. The page has swatches that when clicked need to update the main image and corresponding thumbnails with a new set of images with the new color.  You can view page here: http://www.briansugden.com/ai/tron.html un/pw is ai/ai.

Here's the code I have:

```
<div id="productGallery">

    <div id="tronGallery_1" class="tab">
        <div class="productGalleryMainImg">
            <img id="photoLarge" src="images/tron/tron_satin_1.jpg" width="540" height="415" /></div>

        <div id="productThumbs">

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_1.jpg"><img id="thumb01" src="images/tron/thumb.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb active" /></a>

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_2.jpg"><img id="thumb02" src="images/tron/thumb2.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb" /></a>

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_3.jpg"><img id="thumb03" src="images/tron/thumb.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb" /></a>

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_4.jpg"><img id="thumb04" src="images/tron/thumb.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb" /></a>

        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="tronGallery_2" class="tab">
        <div class="productGalleryMainImg">
            <img id="photoLarge" src="images/tron/tron_satin_1.jpg" width="540" height="415" /></div>

        <div id="productThumbs">

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_1.jpg"><img id="thumb01" src="images/tron/thumb.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb active" /></a>

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_2.jpg"><img id="thumb02" src="images/tron/thumb2.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb" /></a>

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_3.jpg"><img id="thumb03" src="images/tron/thumb.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb" /></a>

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_4.jpg"><img id="thumb04" src="images/tron/thumb.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb" /></a>

        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="tronGallery_3" class="tab">
        <div class="productGalleryMainImg">
            <img id="photoLarge" src="images/tron/tron_satin_1.jpg" width="540" height="415" /></div>

        <div id="productThumbs">

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_1.jpg"><img id="thumb01" src="images/tron/thumb.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb active" /></a>

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_2.jpg"><img id="thumb02" src="images/tron/thumb2.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb" /></a>

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_3.jpg"><img id="thumb03" src="images/tron/thumb.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb" /></a>

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_4.jpg"><img id="thumb04" src="images/tron/thumb.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb" /></a>

        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="tronGallery_4" class="tab">
        <div class="productGalleryMainImg">
            <img id="photoLarge" src="images/tron/tron_satin_1.jpg" width="540" height="415" /></div>

        <div id="productThumbs">

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_1.jpg"><img id="thumb01" src="images/tron/thumb.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb active" /></a>

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_2.jpg"><img id="thumb02" src="images/tron/thumb2.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb" /></a>

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_3.jpg"><img id="thumb03" src="images/tron/thumb.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb" /></a>

            <a href="images/tron/tron_satin_4.jpg"><img id="thumb04" src="images/tron/thumb.jpg" width="100" height="77" class="thumb" /></a>

        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

And the javascript for the main thumbs (change views of main image) as well as the swatches (change whole gallery to a new color):

```
 $(function(evt) {
    $("a:has(img.thumb)").click(function() {
        var largePath = $(this).attr("href");

        $("#photoLarge").attr({ src: largePath });
        return false;

    });

    $("#productThumbs > a > img").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
        $("#productThumbs > a > img").addClass("active").not(this).removeClass("active");
      });

});




$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#tronGallery_2").hide();
            $("#tronGallery_3").hide();
            $("#tronGallery_4").hide();

            var clickHandler = function (link) {
                 $(".tab").hide();
                 $("#tronGallery_" + link.data.id).show();
                 $(".active").removeClass("active");
                 $(this).attr("class","active");
           }

           $(".swatch1").bind("click", {id:"1"} ,clickHandler);
           $(".swatch2").bind("click", {id:"2"} ,clickHandler);
           $(".swatch3").bind("click", {id:"3"} ,clickHandler);
           $(".swatch4").bind("click", {id:"4"} ,clickHandler);

        })
        </script>
```

So the divs arent switching out correctly and the thumbs dont work once you chagne the swatch.  I think I know what the problem is but I dont know how to fix it.  I assume that once I switch out the divs by clicking a swatch its still targeting the div that was hidden instead of the one that's visible. How do I fix that.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First: those are some expensive shoes!

Second: you have lots of duplicate ID values. For example: photoLarge, productThumbs, thumb01, thumb02, thumb03, thumb04. Make those each unique and you will probably get better results.

Third: after the line `$(this).attr("class","active");` you want to have another line to make the first thumbnail active because you removed its active class already. Your HTML marks the first thumbnail active, but that gets removed before it is shown.